# GSI vs redundancy dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have this scenario:

I have to save in dynamoDB table a lot of shops. Every shop has a ID string and its PK.
Every shop has a field "category" that is a string that indicates its category (food,tatoo ...).

So far everything is ok.

I have this use-case: "given in a category get all the stores of that category".

To accomplish this, two options came to my mind:

1. create a GSI that has like PK the "category id" and like field "shop ID".
   In this way with the id of the category I get all the IDs of the stores of that category and then for each store id I query the main table to get all the info of each single store (name, address, etc.).
2. I create in the main table a PK called type "category_$id" (where $id is the category id) and as field the id of the store. This, as in the case of GSI, given a category ID, I have the set of IDs of the shops and then for each ID I execute the query on the same table to get all the info of that shop.

I wanted to know what the difference between these two options is in terms of cost / benefit and which is the best.
They seem to me substantially the same thing (the only difference is that the first uses another table, i.e. the index, while the second uses the same table), but I await the opinion of someone more experienced than me

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One benefit of GSI is that it will result in less management. Lets say you delete/add a record from/to a main table. This will be **automatically be reflected** in your GSI.

In contrast, if you have two independent tables, you have to manage the synchronization between them yourself.

Comment: so the only difference is the management of the deletion / addition of records? in terms of monetary costs are they essentially the same or is one more expensive than the other?

Comment: @Alessio I think cost will be same, or at least I don't know of any major differences.